# Using back references with Xpath 1.0

Tags: xpath

I need to get a node based on another which is at the same level :(

Here is an example :

```
<A>
 <B id=2>
  <F1>aaa</F1>
  <F2>bbb</F2>
  <F3>ccc</F3>
 </B>
 <B>
   ....
 </B>
 <B>
   ....
 </B>
 <D>
  <F1>aaa</F1>
  <F2>bbb</F2>
  <F3>ccc</F3>
  <F4>yyy</F4>
 </D>
 <D>
   ...
 </D>
</A>
```

So I need to get A/D/F4 where A/D/F1=A/B[@id=2]/F1 and A/D/F2=A/B[@id=2]/F2 and A/D/F3=A/B[@id=2]/F3

I only have the id to execute the query and I get the node B as a starting point (returned by other internal code). I was thinking about a way to get a back reference to a node in the path that means I could use something like :

/A/B[@id=2]/../D[F1=Bref/F1 and F2=Bref/F2 and F3=Bref/F3]/F4

I'm trying to not build manually a join and to use only Xpath capabilities if possible.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I totally understand what you mean about backreferences, but do you want something like

```
/A/D[F1 = ../B[@id='2']/F1 and
     F2 = ../B[@id='2']/F2 and
     F3 = ../B[@id='2']/F3]/F4
```

?

In XPath 1.0, there is not a way to create a variable and then dereference it within the same expression. In XPath 2.0, you could use

```
for $b in A/B[@id = '2']
    return A/D[F1 = $b/F1 and F2 = $b/F2 and F3 = $b/F3]/F4
```

but that' won't help you, since your question is about XPath 1.0.

**Update:** per your comment that you're "on node B", I see two possibilities.

One possibility is that the context node is the B element whose @id is the id you've been given, and you want to use the context node rather than looking up B by its @id again. In that case, you might be able to use `current()`:

```
/A/D[F1 = current()/F1 and
     F2 = current()/F2 and
     F3 = current()/F3]/F4
```

`current()` means the context node as it was outside the entire XPath expression.

The other possibility is that the context node is some B element but it may not be the one whose @id you've been given, or you don't care whether it is or not. In that case, just use the first XPath expression I gave above. I just added `/` on the front so that it doesn't matter where in the document the context node was originally.

Comment: Oh, you're right but I forgot to say that I'm on node B :( That's why I'm looking for a back reference. I've updated the question. Yes I can use only Xpath 1.0

Comment: @user2354384: When you say you're on node B, do you mean that the context node is the B element whose id is the id that you've been given? I'll edit my answer accordingly...

Comment: yeah I mean I do something like getB(id=2) which returns me the node B. And now I need to get the node D according to B child values as described above in the question.

Comment: @user2354384: sounds like you could use the first expression, above. You'd just have to construct it to contain the right id. The drawback is the repetition. Alternatively, if you're using XPath within XSLT, you could use `current()` as in the last expression shown above. But you haven't told us if your environment is XSLT or what it is.